# The "Do you want to run this application?" prompt is always displayed for a dynamically generated JNLP. Any way around that?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm using JNLP/Java Web Start on a web application to run a jar on the client computers to do some tasks.
Since I need to pass several parameters (which are always different) to that jar, the JNLP file is generated dynamically on the server.

The problem is that the "Do you want to run this application?" security prompt is displayed **every time** the JNLP is generated and run, even after checking the "Do not show this again..." option. And that can be very inconvenient!

At first, the text of that option was "Do not show this again for **this app from the publisher above**".
But then I added these attributes to the jar's MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Application-Name: The name
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
```

This changed the text of the option to "Do not show this again for **apps from the publisher and location above**", but it still doesn't work.
The prompt is still displayed every time.

The text is no longer referring to that specific application, but is now referring to all applications from that publisher and location. But these never change between invocations of the application!

Am I missing something? Or is that text incorrect? Or is this a bug?

The only solution I found was to create and install a `DeploymentRuleSet.jar` to the client computers, which is a solution I don't like.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour has been marked has "Not an Issue" and has been introduced has a side effect by a [new feature in java 8u112](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8157337).

When href is not specified in jnlp tag, the location of the jnlp is considered unknown and til update java 8u112 it wasn't considered for the info related to the chekbox.
Whith the enhancement implemented with the reported Issue, in these cases, when the checkbox is checked, the info saved together with the certificate of the "producer" are the host of the jar and an hash of the jnlp file.

But in the case of a dynamic jnlp with a changing part (e.g. an argument), the hash will be always different and checkbox will appear each time as it was a different application.

Now arriving good news:

I removed also codebase from jnlp tag and put absolute url in href parameter for jar resources. With such configuration, the app is not considered to be from "multiple host" and the checked flag will refer esclusively at the cert of the Producer and the host of the jar.This solved the Issue: no warning appear again when jnlp file change!

**WARNING**: To make this trick work, you should not use parameter href in any? other tag. For example I realized that having an absolute url defined in href parameter for icon tag makes it work like previously described (checkbox appears each time jnlp changes)

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for redistributable webstart apps as jar hrefs all need to be relative.
Also see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175981 - any redistributable webstart app that changes arguments is not going to provide a good user experience post java 8u112..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "href in the JNLP tag"?

Comment: I have a strange problem. I have a dynamically generated JNLP (changes each time). On my machine with jre 1.8.0_151 after checking the checkbox, it does **not** ask again. But the same jar file with a dynamically generated JNLP at a customers site shows the dialog each time.